# How to find unique keys in a table in SQL

Tags: mysql, sql, database, unique

I have more than 100 tables in SQL which don't have primary keys or indexes on the columns.

I'm manually checking  each column for each table to see whether they have unique keys or not.

How do I query to get unique key columns if they are not present in the table?

Comment: try the below query when you find the particular  column name in a particular table does not need to check every table

Answer (score 0):

Here You Need To Find Column Name Belongs To Particular Table:

```
SELECT c.name AS ColName, t.name AS TableName
FROM sys.columns c
    JOIN sys.tables t ON c.object_id = t.object_id
WHERE c.name LIKE '%write here column name%';
```

Answer (score 0):

Please try following query

```
select stat.table_schema as database_name,
       stat.table_name,
       stat.index_name,
       group_concat(stat.column_name
            order by stat.seq_in_index separator ', ') as columns,
       tco.constraint_type
from information_schema.statistics stat
join information_schema.table_constraints tco
     on stat.table_schema = tco.table_schema
     and stat.table_name = tco.table_name
     and stat.index_name = tco.constraint_name
where stat.non_unique = 0
      and stat.table_schema not in ('information_schema', 'sys',
                                    'performance_schema', 'mysql')
      and (tco.constraint_type !='UNIQUE' OR tco.constraint_type !='PRIMARY KEY') //You can made changes here if needed
group by stat.table_schema,
         stat.table_name,
         stat.index_name,
         tco.constraint_type
order by stat.table_schema,
         stat.table_name;
```

Answer (score 0):

you may want to try something like this

```
SELECT  schema_name(t.schema_id), t.name,  i.name 
FROM sys.indexes i
INNER JOIN sys.tables t ON t.object_id= i.object_id
WHERE i.type>0 and t.is_ms_shipped=0 and t.name<>'sysdiagrams'
and (is_unique_constraint=1)
```

Courtesy: [This link](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/3443/script-all-primary-keys-unique-constraints-and-foreign-keys-in-a-sql-server-database-using-tsql/)